# How can I sort a column based on previous column in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, sql-order-by

I want to sort two columns, which are linked example: I sort a name, and then I want to sort the list of names by date, but, when I do that, it overwrites my sort and sorts it by date and ignores the sort by name,

Is it possible to do sort date by name? When you click a header?
If someone can give me a hint please?

```
$scope.filteredList =null;
$scope.orderByName = function(predicate,reverse){
    if($scope.filteredList == null) {
        $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.dataList, predicate, reverse);
        $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
    }
    else{
    $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,predicate,reverse);
    $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
    }

};
$scope.orderByDate = function(predicate,reverse){
    if($scope.filteredList == null){
        $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.dataList,predicate,reverse);
        $scope.filteredList =  $scope.companyInfo;
    }
    else{
        $scope.companyInfo = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,predicate,reverse);
        $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
    }
};

HTML:

<a ng-click="reverse=!reverse;orderByName('date',reverse)">
<a ng-click="reverse=!reverse;orderByDate('name',reverse)">
```

Here is the code I am using, but every time I click on any of the columns it sorts the data all over again..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write your own order by function. your html may look like:

```
 ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy:mySortFunction"
```

In your function, you may write something like:

```
 $scope.mySortFunction = function(employee) {
    return employee.name + '~' + employee.date;
 };
```

In your case, the below code should work:

```
$scope.filteredList =null;
$scope.orderByName = function(predicate,reverse){
    $scope.sortedOnName = true;
    if($scope.filteredList == null) {
        $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.dataList, predicate, reverse);
        $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
    }
    else{
    $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,predicate,reverse);
    $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
    }

};

 $scope.mySortFunction = function(dataListElement) {
    return dataListElement.name + '~' + dataListElement.date;
 };

$scope.orderByDate = function(predicate,reverse){
    if ($scope.sortedOnName){
      if($scope.filteredList == null){
          $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.dataList,$scope.mySortFunction,reverse);
          $scope.filteredList =  $scope.companyInfo;
      }
      else{
          $scope.companyInfo = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,$scope.mySortFunction,reverse);
          $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
      }
    }
    else {
      if($scope.filteredList == null){
          $scope.dataList = $filter("orderBy")($scope.dataList,predicate,reverse);
          $scope.filteredList =  $scope.companyInfo;
      }
      else{
          $scope.companyInfo = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,predicate,reverse);
          $scope.filteredList =  $scope.dataList;
      }
    }
};
```

Theoretically it should, but if you do some corrections to make it work, please let me know so that I can update the answer.

Comment: Hi Anshman, I have tried the one below:


 $scope.orderByName = function(predicate,reverse){
                if($scope.filteredList == null) {
                    $scope.ListInfo = $filter("orderBy")($scope.ListInfo, predicate, reverse);
                    $scope.filteredList =  $scope.ListInfo;
                }
                else{
                    $scope.companyInfo = $filter("orderBy")($scope.filteredList,predicate,reverse);
                    $scope.filteredList =  $scope.ListInfo;
                }

which should sort my data both ways,

Comment: Its a table, that has 2 columns, that when I click on name, it is sorted and then when I click on the date, the date should be sorted based on the name, it should not change the result again, that is what I am trying to do
I am implementing it on an ng-onclick

Comment: Can you please put your code in your question, so that is is more readable. I will try to understand your problem first

Comment: you got any solution for it? am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hi Anshuman thanks for the help, It is still same, when I try to sort the name and then the date,it again sorts all the table and ignores the sorted name column, I want to sort a column and then freeze it and then sort another column based on the frozen column. but not sure what is wrong.